# Fifa Tactical defending control combination on PS4

Tags: ps4, fifa-15

I am trying to learn Tactical Defending for the sake of Fifa 15 online play (since there is no more head to head where we could use legacy defending if we wanted). I am struggling so much to get the ball from the opponent. I use L2 to Jockey and when I think I have an opportunity I press 'o' or release L2 which I understand makes my player try to get the ball. But that fails almost all the time. My defender looks like a fool putting his leg out where the ball is not. Sometimes I use 'x' to press and then 'o' when there is an opportunity but that does not work for me either. All I can do is rush tackle from the front to get the ball and counter quickly, after which If I lose the ball again I will have to spent minutes trying to get it back. Could someone please help with a defending strategy in terms of controls.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I cried when I had to use tactical defending.
But after numerous attempts I found somethings that works for me.

-Make sure you are mostly facing your opponent and not running behind him. That means dont rush into a player let him come close to you then do the tackling.
-Along with jockey you should use team-mate contain(if you start using this feature you will get similar feel as legacy defending)
- Mostly jockey on the wings not in the middle of the park.
- In the middle of the park use the normal contain
- Always always watch out for through balls as soon as you see them coming start running back wards

After using all these techniques you will start seeing a lot of interceptions(specially by using teammate contain)

BEST OF LUCK!

Comment: Good suggestions, but can't contain to jockeying containing forever, have to make a move to get the ball, when the player come close enough like you mentioned. Its when I try to make a move that my player looks like a fool. Just feels like I am missing something.